# Disable or Hide selected ng-options angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown box where a input box is added once you select an option, but I want disable/hide/remove once that options is selected and then enable the option again once the input box is removed. Is the disabled expression the best option to go.
Any help will be appreciates

http://plnkr.co/edit/PPDYKjztPF528yli9FbN?p=preview

```
 <fieldset>
    <div ng-repeat="choice in formOptionData track by $index">
      <a class="remove-field remove u-pull-right" ng-click="remove()">Remove</a>
      <input id="input{{choice.name}}" placeholder="{{choice.label}}" type="number" name="{{choice.name}}">
    </div>  
      <div id="add-more" class="well">
        <div class="field">
          <div style="width:100%;" class="dropdown">
            <select name="{{options.name}}" id="select" data-ng-model="selectedValue[options.name]" data-ng-options="options as options.label for options in element.inputElement | orderBy:'label'" ng-change="onCategoryChange(selectedValue)">
              <option value="" data-id="null" disabled="" selected="">Select an item...</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      {{formData}}
    </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Try use `ng-disabled=expression`. There `expression` is angular expression, evaluate to true or false.

Comment: Ok I added  ng-selected="inputSelection = 'Choose from the list'" ng-disabled="options === inputSelection"> but seems to disable the whole box, just want the individual option disabled.

Comment: Add `ng-disabled` on **option** tag. Or provide working plunk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of modification to be done to your code to get the functionality you want. I took the liberty to fork your plunk to implement this functionality.

Your plunk initially didn't work, since your markup had a lot of mistakes.

1. You were iterating over non-existing array `questionList` I changed it to `item`

   ```
   <div ng-repeat="element in questionList">
   //changed to
   <div ng-repeat="element in item">
   ```
2. I think you're referring to `question` as your controller's scope, multiple times in your code. to do that you have to use use `ng-controller="QuestionController as question"` but I don't do that so I have removed all the references to `question` and furthermore since you need different options for different items so you should be making `forOptionData` specific to `element` in question.

   ```
   <div ng-repeat="choice in question.formOptionData track by $index">
   //changed to
   <div ng-repeat="choice in element.formOptionData track by $index">
   ```
3. Since you want individual option to be disabled you should not use `ng-options` as it doesn't provide such functionality, instead you should repeat over the options array in a separate `<option>` tag. with some object attribute for `ng-disabled` as I have attached the `selectable` attribute to the option object. **Note: `value` of option is usually `id` or something but since you are using the complete object it is not possible to us it in the `value` attribute so I have passed the index and grabbing the object using its index**

   ```
   <select name="" id="select" data-ng-model="selectedValue" data-ng-options="options as options.label for options in element.inputElement | orderBy:'label'" ng-change="question.onSelectionChange(selectedValue)">
     <option value="" data-id="null" disabled="" selected="">Select an item...</option>
   </select>
   //changed to
   <select name="" id="select" ng-model="element.selectedValue"  ng-change="onSelectionChange(element,element.inputElement[element.selectedValue])" ng-init="element.formOptionData=[];selectedValue=''">
     <option value="" data-id="null" disabled="true" selected="">Select an item...</option>
     <option ng-repeat="options in element.inputElement | orderBy:'label' track by $index" ng-disabled="!options.selectable" value="{{$index}}" ng-init="options.selectable = true">{{options.label}}</option>
   </select>
   ```
4. I have changed your JS that handles `remove` and `selectChange` functionality to cater these new changes.

   ```
   $scope.onSelectionChange = function(selectedItem) {
     this.formOptionData.push(selectedItem);
   };
   $scope.remove = function(element) {
     this.formOptionData.splice(element, 1);
   };
   //changed to
   $scope.onSelectionChange = function(element, selectedItem) {
     selectedItem.selectable = false; //disable since selected
     console.log(selectedItem)
     element.formOptionData.push(selectedItem); //push to element specific formOptionData. or it'll be shared.
     console.log(element)
   };
   $scope.remove = function(choice, element, $index) {
     temp = element.formOptionData.splice($index, 1)[0];//spliced object is returned as array. take first element of it
     console.log(temp)
     temp.selectable = true;//since removed enable it back.
   };
   ```

[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/tV1fS7hzjAfQLN5zLjEb?p=preview)

## Note: It is your responsibility to clean this messy code.

## whew....

---

check this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/tV1fS7hzjAfQLN5zLjEb?p=preview) and compare it with your [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PPDYKjztPF528yli9FbN?p=preview)

Comment: It not possible to give all the connected parts to the code as it is so big, so tried to give snap shot of components, I needed to get working. But thank I will try your solution against my code.

Comment: Oh yes, a few little tweeks here and there. Thanks very much

Comment: @NiseNise It took me an hour to implement this.